# Getting error while Joining a 14 billion record table (Size : 2 TB) and a 2 billion table (10 GB) in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing issue while joining(Inner join) a 2TB table with a 10 GB table(its a dimension table and joining column is unique) in Spark .

My spark configurations are :

1. Executor memory : 30 GB
2. Number of Executor : 100
3. Number of cores per executor : 4

I am getting below Error while joining :

> Application is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage:
>   9.0 GB of 9 GB physical memory used; 10.9 GB of 18.9 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.

It would be really helpful if some can help me to have a good strategy to do such huge joins .

```
Application application_1484081373244_3987 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1484081373244_3987_000002 exited with exitCode: -104
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:https://cdts1hdpnn01d.rxcorp.com:8090/proxy/application_1484081373244_3987/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Container [pid=17580,containerID=container_e75_1484081373244_3987_02_000001] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 9.5 GB of 9 GB physical memory used; 11.7 GB of 18.9 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_e75_1484081373244_3987_02_000001 :
|- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
|- 17580 17575 17580 17580 (bash) 3 0 109068288 392 /bin/bash -c LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p2004.2082/lib/hadoop/../../../CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p2004.2082/lib/hadoop/lib/native: /usr/java/latest/bin/java -server -Xmx8192m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data09/yarn/nm/usercache/clsuusr/appcache/application_1484081373244_3987/container_e75_1484081373244_3987_02_000001/tmp '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:logs.properties' -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/data07/yarn/container/application_1484081373244_3987/container_e75_1484081373244_3987_02_000001 org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster --class 'TransTableCreation' --jar file:/storage/acceptance/cls/data01/CustomTransTable-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --executor-memory 20480m --executor-cores 4 --properties-file /data09/yarn/nm/usercache/clsuusr/appcache/application_1484081373244_3987/container_e75_1484081373244_3987_02_000001/__spark_conf__/__spark_conf__.properties 1> /data07/yarn/container/application_1484081373244_3987/container_e75_1484081373244_3987_02_000001/stdout 2> /data07/yarn/container/application_1484081373244_3987/container_e75_1484081373244_3987_02_000001/stderr
|- 17589 17580 17580 17580 (java) 45896 1279 12430073856 2477874 /u
```

Comment: There was a setting in spark to spill data to disk when it doesn't fit in memory (*can't remember the name right now*). Do you have that turned on?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/29494411/647053